# Cannot invoke MySQL interactive mode in Powershell

Tags: command-line, powershell, mysql

I can't run MySQL.exe in interactive mode in Powershell on a Nano Server installation. I have initialized the data folder with `mysqld.exe --initialize`. The password is output to the file `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\data\ServerName.err`.

I type the command: `mysql.exe -u root -ppassword`, where I enter the randomly-generated password.

If the password is correct, I get:

`mysql.exe : mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`

And then it returns me to the prompt.

If I do not specify a password when using -p or --password, the client program is supposed to solicit the password interactively. When I try that, I don't get any prompt, nothing written to the console, and when I press CTRL-C, I get:

`The remote pipeline has been stopped.`

Are these executables capable of being run under a Powershell remote session? Is there something wrong with the way I'm trying to use the console? Maybe this a problem with my Powershell configuration?

**Update:** After deleting and reinitializing the data folder, I keep getting `Access denied for user 'ser=root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)` when I enter the randomly generated password using the following command: `& mysql –user=root –password=(password)`. I have also tried to change the password using a text file with `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';` in it, but when I do that, I have to press CTRL-C to return to the prompt, as stated previously. Looking at the error log, MySQL claims to have processed the text file, but I still can't logon.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say explicitly which PowerShell host you are using. You might be using PowerShell ISE, as per: [How to access Nano Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt708805(v=vs.85).aspx)

If you are using PowerShell ISE this (using **mysql.exe** interactively) probably won't work, as **powershell_ise.exe** doesn't support interactive tools in the same way that plain old **powershell.exe** does. This is discussed a little on the following Stack Overflow question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/q/48120827/5771128

In this case, try **powershell.exe** instead.